# how can get orders in magento 1 using rest api through postman

Tags: magento-1.9, product, orders, configuration, authorize

i have consumer key and secret and access token generated through

1. https://mydomain/oauth/initiate
2. oauth/initiate
3. /oauth/token

I'm trying to get orders using https://mydomain/api/rest/orders and getting "Access denied" in response. How can I solve it? Please provide Magento 1 resources and ideas on how to resolve this issue.

Please guide how can access orders in mangento 1.9 using postman. i have created one consumer and using them i got token but that still not working.

Please help me; I don't have any idea how to grant permissions from the admin panel.